# How to sync 1) EC2 volume attachment's name with 2) a variable in EC2's user-data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ebs

Rephrasing the title, how to *not* have to guess the EC2 attached volume/device's name in generated `aws_instance`'s `user_data`? That is, how to *not* be forced to have an additional `attached_device_actual_name` variable in below Terraform `locals`?

Here's the relevant Terraform configuration:

```
locals {
  attached_device_name        = "/dev/sdf"     # Used in `aws_volume_attachment`.
  attached_device_actual_name = "/dev/nvme1n1" # Used in `templatefile`.
}
resource "aws_instance" "foo" {
  user_data = templatefile("./user-data.sh.tpl", {
    attached_device_name = local.attached_device_actual_name
  })
}
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "foo" {
  device_name = local.attached_device_name
  instance_id = aws_instance.foo.id
}
```

[The docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/device_naming.html#available-ec2-device-names) say

> The device names that you specify for NVMe EBS volumes in a block device mapping are renamed using NVMe device names (`/dev/nvme[0-26]n1`).

Does the above-quoted part `"device names [...] are renamed"` also imply that one should *not* use these, reserved `/dev/nvme...` names? Indeed, if I set `local.attached_device_name` to `/dev/nvme1n1`, which is a "correct" guess in this case, this error pops up:

> Error: Error attaching volume (vol-some_id) to instance (i-some_id), message: "Value (/dev/nvme1n1) for parameter device is invalid. /dev/nvme1n1 is not a valid EBS device name.", code: "InvalidParameterValue"
> "/dev/nvme1n1 is not a valid EBS device name."

The goal was to have `user_data` synced with the attached-volume's name and then be able to wait for the volume:

```
DEVICE="${attached_device_name}"

while [ ! -e "$${DEVICE}" ] ; do
  echo "Waiting for $DEVICE ..."
  sleep 1
done
```

Env:

```
Terraform 1.1.2
hashicorp/aws 4.10.0
```

Comment: The volume naming convention is pretty explicit (this URL is for Linux instances): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/device_naming.html#available-ec2-device-names. The `aws_volume_attachment` resource exports the `device_name` attribute so it could in theory be used as a parameter passed to the `templatefile` function.

Comment: Though I have a feeling it would cause a cyclic dependency if used.

Comment: Indeed, an `Error: Cycle: aws_volume_attachment.foo, aws_instance.foo, aws_ebs_volume.foo` occurs. So, is there no other way, considering quoted docs, but to hardcode and guess the resulting device name (`/dev/nvme1n1` in this case)?

Comment: It seems so, but let me ask you a question: does it really have to be a device name that is passed? Can you not use a built-in command in the userdata script to fetch the devices available to the instance, something like `lsblk`?

Comment: It doesn't - `user_data` script could dynamically discover which is the newly attached device. It's unfortunate though that _the script itself_ should hold the pre-set knowledge to look for `nvme[0-26]n1`, which is now divorced and physically separate from the `.tf` script, where the EC2 `instance_type` is set, and volume(s) are attached. (There's also an additional implicit knowledge that `nvme0n1` is already present, i.e. _not_ newly attached.)